# How to filter a list with a list of strings in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of objects and want to filter all elements whose name is like one of the strings in a list.
My current approach is to use `where-object`, but this results in a long chain of calls to where-object.

```
Get-AppxPackage |
    where-object {$_.name -notlike "*store*"} |
    where-object {$_.name -notlike "*MSPaint*"} ...
```

I would like to reduce the boilerplate needed here as I expect the list of strings to get quite large.
I would further like to be able to use the filter on another output, which seems I am currently only able to do by copy pasting the where-object block.

Comment: where-object {$_.name -notlike "*store*" -and $_.name -notlike "*MSPaint*" } should work

Comment: That is slightly better, but it still requires me to copy/paste that `where-object` construct if I want to filter another output with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use regex `notmatch` instead. This will be a lot faster to execute.
Something like

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.name -notmatch 'store|MSPaint'}
```

Instead of typing in the literal names to *not* match, you can build the pattern from an array or by reading in a textfile.
Lets say you have a list of names in a textfile

```
store
MSPaint
...
```

You can then read in this file as array with

```
$list = Get-Content -Path "<PATH TO THE FILE>"
```

Next combine this list to build the pattern like

```
$pattern = (($list | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) –join "|")
```

and do

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.name -notmatch $pattern}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this code shows how to filter using -and and -or in the where-object

```
class cCustomField
{
[string] $Id
[string] $Name
[string] $Description
[string] $Type
[bool] $On_projects
[bool] $On_people
} 
$list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[cCustomField]
 ... load your data ....
 filter using -and -or 
$my_object=$list | Where-Object {$_.name -EQ 'gender' -and $_.on_people -EQ $true  }
```